# Why two focus controls on Canon KT14X44KRS?

Tags: lenses, focus

Apologies if this is a video camera question rather than a video question.

My JVC GY-HM700 camera lens, Canon KT14x44KRS has both a focus control, that goes from relatively close to infinity, and a macro control that shifts the entire focal range closer, starting somewhere inside the lens hood.

This means that if I'm filming something moving towards the lens, at some point I have to take my hand off the focus control and quickly adjust the macro control, then go back to the focus control.

Is this so that you have finer control of the focus when focusing on something that doesn't move too far toward or away from the lens? I guess I just find it a confusing control scheme, as I would have expected one focus control to cover the entire range. Is it because it's implemented with multiple Independent lenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many lenses of different types have separate Macro modes that allow the photographer to focus on objects that are closer than they normally would be able to. Generally this Macro mode would apply if the object is within 1' of the lens.

There are plenty of ways to work around this limitation creatively, and nicer and more expensive lenses may offer better performance.

I did check the manual for camera, and it doesn't have any information about the Macro mode unfortunately.